# Criar e atribuir variáveis em loop For

Tags: javascript, jquery, loop, lógica, otimização

Como fazer esta logica dentro de um *loop* `FOR` ?

```js
var G1 = $('#G1').text()
var G2 = $('#G2').text()
var G3 = $('#G3').text()

console.log("NaN")
console.log(G1+"\n"+G2+"\n"+G3)
console.log(G1+G2+G3)

G1 = parseFloat(G1)
G2 = parseFloat(G2)
G3 = parseFloat(G3)

console.log("Agora Números")
console.log(G1+"\n"+G2+"\n"+G3)
console.log(G1+G2+G3)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<p id="G1">10</p>
<p id="G2">20</p>
<p id="G3">30</p>
```

Comment: Onde vais usar os valores de `G1, G2, etc...`? esses elementos têm um elemento pai comum?

Comment: O que você quer fazer mais expecificamente? Não está claro o bastante

Comment: Você está querendo pegar o texto das "id" e fazer o que exatamente dentro do for??

Comment: É simplesmente pegar as variaveis dos `p` e somar. O Maniero♦ respondeu exatamente o que eu precisava. Obrigado :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sempre que você tem uma variável com um prefixo em comum e em seguida vem um número formando uma sequência, na verdade você não deveria ter várias variáveis, deveria ter um *array*, assim o prefixo fica o nome do *array* e a sequência fica o índice do *array*, desta forma você pode criar um laço e usar a variável dela como índice deste *array*.

```js
var G = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    G[i] = $('#G' + (i + 1)).text();
}
console.log("NaN");
var soma = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    console.log(G[i] + "\n");
    soma += G[i];
}
console.log(soma)
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    G[i] = parseFloat(G[i]);
}
console.log("Agora Números")
var soma = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    console.log(G[i] + "\n");
    soma += G[i];
}
console.log(soma)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p id="G1">10</p>
<p id="G2">20</p>
<p id="G3">30</p>
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Syntax/VariableInLoop.js).

Tem maneiras mais modernas de fazer isto, mas nem todo navegador aceita.

Comment: Perfeito! Obrigado!!

Answer (score 2):

```js
var elems = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.getElementsByTagName('p'));

console.log(NaN);
elems.forEach(function(elem){
  console.log(elem.innerText);
});

console.log("Agora Números")
let aux = 0;
elems.forEach(function(elem){
  var i = parseFloat(elem.innerText);
  console.log(i);
  aux += i;
});

console.log(aux);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<p id="G1">10</p>
<p id="G2">20</p>
<p id="G3">30</p>
```